# Unable to access CQ5 servlet from standalone java program

Tags: aem

I have a CQ5 servlet and i am able to invoke this servlet from within the AEM environment. I have a requirement to access this servlet from a standalone java program. This servlet returns a json.

My CQ5 servlet is as below:

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = false)
@Service
@Properties({
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = "/bin/jsonServlet"),
        @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "GET") })
public class JsonServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {


    private Resource resource;

    @Reference
    private DataSourcePool dataSourceService;

    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        response.setHeader(CONTENTTYPE, APPLICATIONJSON);
        DataSource dataSource;
        try {
            log.info("***Inside JsonServlet***");
            JSONObject courseObject = new JSONObject();
            dataSource = (DataSource) dataSourceService.getDataSource("IDATASOURCE");
            List<Map<String, String>> dbColValsList = DownloadCoursesDBHelper.fetchCoursesLite(dataSource);         
            int courseIndex=0;
            for(Map<String, String> propertyVals:dbColValsList){
                JSONObject propertyList = generatePropertyList(propertyVals);
                if (propertyList != null) {
                    courseObject.put(COURSE+courseIndex++, propertyList);
                }
            }
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().println(courseObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error"
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My standalone java program accessing this servlet is as as below:

```
package com.aem.servlet;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

public class InvokeSlingServlet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Create an HTTPClient object
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("http://localhost:4502/bin/jsonServlet");

        client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope("localhost",4502), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin"));
        //method.setDoAuthentication( true );
        try {
            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                System.out.println("HTTP Method failed: "
                        + method.getStatusLine());
            }

            // Read the response body.
            byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

            System.out.println("INVOKED THE AEM SLING SERVLET!!! " + new String(responseBody));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

When i run the java program, i get a response:
**HTTP Method failed: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**

please let me know whether i need to configure any setting in AEM environment and also do i need to make any changes to my standalone java program.

Comment: Check if servlet URL is accessible in browser

Comment: Check your database configuration. Generally when you think everything else is set up correctly, a servlet simply won't work because one or more of  its `@Reference` dependencies can't be met. This will be reported in the error log - you can add an `@Activate` method with a debug log just to make it a little easier to find.